# Show messagebox, but without the buttons

Tags: c#, messagebox, custom-action

From my windows installer custom action, I want to show some small window that tells the user what I am doing right now.

I know that I can show a message with

```
MessageBox.Show("Error while signing in: Credentials for mail address " + username + " did not suffice for authentication", "Authentication error");
```

But before I can throw the error, I have to wait for timeout, which can take some seconds, and I want the user to know that I am trying:

```
MessageBox.Show("Validating credentials against Exchange Webservice", "Validating credentials");
```

So I tried to remove the buttons:

```
MessageBox.Show("Validating credentials against Exchange Webservice", "Validating credentials", MessageBoxButtons.NONE);
```

but there is no "NONE" buttons, I always have to choose at least one (for instance "OK"). What am I missing here?

Comment: Make your own.. messagebox requires you have a message and acknowledge it, therefore has to have a button.. if you want to just display a window for 20s or whatever, make your own window

Comment: What do you want?? The Messagebox stand there forever? Close it with a timer, even if the user has not really read or comprehended to message?? Rolling your own is probably the way to go, as you can change the status info while you progress.

Comment: @TaW I want to close the box when the work is done. If that's fast enough that the user doesn't have time to read the message, it ought to be okay for him, since the installer proceeds to the next dialog.